# How to add a City to test data with data type

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to add another city to the test data and would like to maintain the cities in alphabetical order. The test data and data type is below:

```
data City = City {city:: String, northDeg:: Int, southDeg:: Int, populationPerYear:: [Int]}
    deriving (Show, Read)

testData :: [City]
testData = [
    City "Amsterdam" 52 5 [1158, 1149, 1140, 1132],
    City "Athens" 38  23    [3153, 3153, 3154, 3156],
    City "Berlin" 53  13    [3567, 3562, 3557, 3552],
    City "Brussels" 51   4    [2096, 2081, 2065, 2050],
    City "Bucharest" 44  26    [1794, 1803, 1812, 1821],
    City "London"       52   0    [9426, 9304, 9177, 9046],
    City "Madrid"       40   4    [6669, 6618, 6559, 6497],
    City "Paris"        49   2    [11079, 11017, 10958, 10901],
    City  "Rome"         42  13    [4278, 4257, 4234, 4210],
    City "Sofia"        43  23    [1284, 1281, 1277, 1272],
    City  "Vienna"       48  16    [1945, 1930, 1915, 1901],
    City "Warsaw"       52  21    [1790, 1783, 1776, 1768]
    ]
```

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: And, taken literally, your question could be answered “manually go through the list until you find the first the comes alphabetically after the one you want to insert. Edit your source file by inserting the new city before that one”. (There's, that's actually an algorithm you can also implement in Haskell...)

Comment: The question is more like how to maintain the lines in a sorted order. Could you use the editor feature (e.g., In vim `:sort`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `insertBag` or `insertSet` from [`Data.List.Ordered`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html).

Add `Eq` and `Ord` to your derived instances, and you're good to go:

```
import Data.List.Ordered(insertBag)

data City = City {city:: String, northDeg:: Int, southDeg:: Int, populationPerYear:: [Int]}
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

testData :: [City]
testData = [
    City "Amsterdam" 52 5 [1158, 1149, 1140, 1132],
    City "Athens" 38  23    [3153, 3153, 3154, 3156],
    City "Berlin" 53  13    [3567, 3562, 3557, 3552],
    City "Brussels" 51   4    [2096, 2081, 2065, 2050],
    City "Bucharest" 44  26    [1794, 1803, 1812, 1821],
    City "London"       52   0    [9426, 9304, 9177, 9046],
    City "Madrid"       40   4    [6669, 6618, 6559, 6497],
    City "Paris"        49   2    [11079, 11017, 10958, 10901],
    City  "Rome"         42  13    [4278, 4257, 4234, 4210],
    City "Sofia"        43  23    [1284, 1281, 1277, 1272],
    City  "Vienna"       48  16    [1945, 1930, 1915, 1901],
    City "Warsaw"       52  21    [1790, 1783, 1776, 1768]
    ]
addLA = insertBag (City "Los Angeles" 1 1 []) testData
    
main = putStrLn $ show $ addLA
```